# NestJS - Response from decorator @Res() is null in microservice

Tags: download, stream, pipe, microservices, nestjs

When building a microservice system using NestJS, I am trying to let the client side download by calling an API of the storage service. Download requests are sent to the API gateway to the storage service to get the required files by a `ClientProxy`.
This is the code in the API gateway:

```
@Post('/storage/file')
public async getLog(@Body() request: GetFileRequest): Promise<any> {
  return this.storageClient.send('get_file', request);
}
```

This is the code in the `StorageService`

```
@MessagePattern('get_file')
public async getFile(@Body() request: GetFileRequest, @Res() res: Response): Promise<Buffer> {
  const fileStream = await this.fileService.getFile(request);

  if (!fileStream)
    throw new RpcException('Failed to retrieve file');

  res.set({ 'Content-Type': 'text/csv' });
  fileStream.pipe(res);
}
```

However, the `res` object is null so that I cannot access to its `set` method, and I am probably sure that the `fileStream` cannot pipe a null response. Is there any defects in my code or which steps I probably missed?

Comment: What is your microservice transport type? I don't think`@Res()` is injecting what you think it is

Comment: @JayMcDoniel My microservice's transport type is TCP. If not ```@Res()``` then which decorator should be imported?

Comment: What's wrong with just returning the stream as a buffer, and then letting the gateway handle the streaming of it to the client?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Injecting `@Res()` to the controller at the gateway makes my app freeze (stuck at "Sending request"). Besides, the `ClientProxy.send()` method return an `Observable`, and when I try to subscribe it to get the result, the result is `undefined`.

Comment: I've retrieved the observable's result by converting it to a promise. But when I tried to pipe the response into the `ReadStream` it said `ReadStream.pipe() is not a function`. The ReadStream is created using `fs.createReadStream()`